# Problem with bitcoin-cli -datadir flag

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

I moved my blockchain directory, including `bitcoin.conf`, to an external drive `D:\Bitcoin`. Bitcoin Core starts and runs normally using this path, however when I try to use the command line interface, even when I specify the new directory, I keep running into this error.

```
C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon>bitcoin-cli -datadir=D:\Bitcoin -getinfo 

   error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is  not set. See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass.
```

I know that the issue is that `bitcoin-cli` is still looking in the default directory `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin` because when I copy the auth `.cookie` and `bitcoin.conf` files to to old directory my commands work.

Wondering if the `-datadir` flag is not working properly, if I made an error somewhere, or if there is another way to fix this? I have also tried using the `-conf=D:\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf` flag, however that does not fix either.

Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around the datadir, e.g. `-datadir="D:\Bitcoin"`?

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Chow suggested, the solution was simply putting quotes around the directory path. Windows SMH. Thank you.